# What is a practical real world problem that requires the usage of matrix factorization

Tags: matrix-decomposition

I am not asking about the various methods of decomposing a matrix. I am looking for a real world problem that can be represented in matrix form and then can be solved using the concepts of decomposition. i.e in short, why do we need to learn matrix decomposition?

Comment: Here's one: What sort of questions can you give your students? :-P

Comment: Could you please be more specific about which matrix decomposition method you were talking about? There are so many kinds of matrix decomposition.

Comment: I was referring to SVD,LU and Cholesky. These are the only ones I know somewhat.